# Broken tempdb location and can't recover

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, tempdb, disaster-recovery

Made a mistake and mistyped an alter database command for tempdb.

Now the instance won't start. I can't start in single user mode using -m as it states the tempdb could not be found. I tried using:

```
net start msqsqlserver /f /t3608
```

But then I can't actually connect to the instance at all using either `sqlcmd` or `ssms`.

Comment: What does the SQL server error log say?

Comment: What change did you make?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Start SQL Server as an application, not a service, in minimal config mode, and only recovering master, from a command prompt:

```
[path to this instance]\BINN\sqlservr.exe -c -f -T3608
```

(Add `-s InstanceName` if this is a named instance.)

Now, in a different command prompt, connect using SQLCMD:

```
sqlcmd -S InstanceName -E
```

And issue a correction (triple-check this!!!), then shut the application down:

```
> ALTER DATABASE tempdb MODIFY FILE ...
> SHUTDOWN WITH NOWAIT;
> GO
```

Comment: I did end up getting in via this method though I am unsure initially why it was not letting me connect.  In the end I disabled all the services, bounced the box and ran the VM without a network connection and it seemed to work.  Thanks for the pointers though.  Hope this is useful for someone else in the future too!

Answer (score 0):

1. Start sql server in single user mode - 
   Net Start MSSQLServer /mSQLCMD /f/t3608
2. To be in single user mode sqlcmd -S. –E
3. Run the commands

Alter database tempdb modify file (name = tempdev, filename = 'E:\SQLDATA\DEFAULT\tempdb.mdf')

Alter database tempdb modify file (name = templog, filename = 'E:\SQLDATA\DEFAULT\Templog.ldf')

4. Stop sql server 
   Net stop mssqlserver